# C# DoNET 5 link a library with Dynamic DLL

Tags: c#, dll, reflection, static

I face an issue when i try to use a function from a .NET C# library class link to another library class loaded by Reflection

**Here the Application call :**

```
       private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            // Call static
            var lib = new StaticLib.StaticClass();
            var a = lib.Test(1); // Works fine


            // Call dynamic
            var DLL = Assembly.LoadFile(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + System.IO.Path.DirectorySeparatorChar + "DynamicLib.dll");

            var theType = DLL.GetType("DynamicLib.DynamicClass");
            var inst =  Activator.CreateInstance(theType);
            
            var method_1 = theType.GetMethod("GetInvert_1");
            var b = method_1.Invoke(inst, new object[] { 1 }); // Works fine
            
            var method_2 = theType.GetMethod("GetInvert_2");
            var c = method_2.Invoke(inst, new object[] { 1 }); // Exception
        }
```

**The Dynamic library :**

```
namespace DynamicLib
{
    public class DynamicClass
    {
        public static int GetInvert_1(int value)
        {
            return value * (-1);
        }

        public static int GetInvert_2(int value)
        {
            var lib = new StaticLib.StaticClass();
            return lib.Test(value);
        }
    }
}
```

**The Static library used by the dynamic library** :

```
namespace StaticLib
{
    public class StaticClass
    {
        public int Test(int value)
        {
            return value * (-1);
        }
    }
}
```

- Tha call **var lib = new StaticLib.StaticClass(); var a = lib.Test(1);** : Works perfectly
- The call **var a = method_1.Invoke(c, new object[] { 1 });** works perfectly.
- The call **var b = method_2.Invoke(c, new object[] { 1 });** crashes at the right moment of Invoke. If i remove the call to StaticLibray.StaticClass.test, there is no problem.

> Exception interne 1 :
> FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'StaticLib, Version=1.0.0.0, >Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Le fichier spécifié est introuvable.

It makes me confused, because through the Dynamic library, i can not call the function Test. The file StaticLib.dll is in the same directory than the other files. If i remove the file StaticLib.dll, i can even not start the application. So the problem comes to the link between DynamicLib.dll and StaticLink.Dll

thank for help

Comment: Have you tried to load both assemblies?

Comment: Hi,
I need both. It comes from another project. In the dynamic library, i load another static libraries 5 libs made for .NET framework 4,7), but i face the problem only this new one.

I need one dynamic and one static.

Comment: Have a look at [MS Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.reflection.assembly.loadfrom?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-6.0#System_Reflection_Assembly_LoadFrom_System_String_) I think you'll find the solution there. The Remarks section.

Comment: is your StaticLib in the same folder with DynamicLib when you debug or release. Or did you add StaticLibray to project dependencies of DynamicLib

Comment: McNets : You got the gold medal. Thanx a lot for everyone.

Answer (score 0):

According to McNets, here is the solution :

Create the app.config file if it does not exist, and add :

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <loadFromRemoteSources enabled="true"/>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Be carefull :

> CAS is not supported in .NET Core, .NET 5, or later versions. CAS is not supported by versions of C# later than 7.0.

[For late versions of .NET, use appdomain](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/framework/code-access-security/how-to-run-partially-trusted-code-in-a-sandbox)